# Do I need to use type long to store 2166136261 in Java?

Tags: java, hash, int, long-integer

I'm attempting to implement a simple [FNV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) hash function in Java. The function requires the value 2166136261 as a function parameter. In one [online source](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/FNVHash.htm), the number is assigned as follows in hexadecimal:

```
private static final int FNV_32_INIT = 0x811C9DC5;
```

But I don't think this is correct since 2166136261 is larger than 2147483647 which is the largest value an `int` can hold.

Am I right in assuming that I would need at least a variable of type `long` in order to store the value, regardless of decimal or hexadecimal?

---

Edit:

The value used as the offset basis in this algorithm is arbitrary, so it doesn't matter whether FNV_32_INIT = 2166136261 or some other value:

> Regarding the offset_basis value:
>
> The switch from FNV-0 to FNV-1 was purely to change the offset_basis
>   to a non-zero value. The selection of that non-zero value is
>   arbitrary. The string: chongo  /../\ was used
>   because the tester was looking at an EMail message from Landon in
>   Landon's standard EMail signature line. Actually the person who did
>   that did not see very well. Landon, today, uses ()'s instead of <>'s
>   and his ASCII bats use "oo" eyes instead of ".." as in: chongo (Landon
>   Curt Noll) /\oo/\ We didn't bother correcting her error because it
>   does not matter. In the general case, almost any offset_basis will
>   serve so long as it is non-zero.

[Source](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/)

Comment: *Am I right in assuming that I would need at least a variable of type long in order to store the value, regardless of decimal or hexadecimal?* **YES**. And you add a `L` to indicate the constant value is a `long`; `long hex = 0x811C9DC5L;`. And the value is correct, when you understand ***overflow***.

Comment: @Elliott So the online source is wrong?

Comment: I would assume the online source understands overflow.

Comment: The online source doesn't seem to claim that 0x811C9DC5 equals 2166136261.

Comment: I don't see a comment in the source. But if they aren't using `2166136261`, why do they assume `-2128831035` will behave the same in the hash function? The hash function specifies `2166136261`.

Comment: @Kevin I'm sorry, I added that comment myself. I've changed it to reflect the original source's format. I understand there is overflow. I suppose this raises another question with regards specifically to the FNV algorithm. All other implementations of the algorithm I see use 2166136261. [example1](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=service-discovery-master/client/src/main/java/com/nesscomputing/service/discovery/client/internal/HashAlgorithm.java). [example2](https://github.com/jakedouglas/fnv-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitlove/FNV.java)

Comment: @Kevin It didn't occur to me that there would be overflow until after I had asked the question. To be honest, I probably should have asked my question regarding the online source's implementation rather than storing a value as a `long` vs `int`. The source is clearly using a different value than is specified in the algorithm. I guess that's what I'm really confused about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136919/discussion-between-why-and-kevin).

Comment: The source uses a unsigned integer, java only has signed integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.

Whether it's expressed in decimal, hex, binary, octal, base 64, or any other radix, the expressions all represent the same magnitude.